# Most popular screen sizes/resolutions on Android phones

Tags: android, screen-resolution, screen-size

I understand that Android's developer site provides information on this topic. I have already read the following three pages:

- [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [Screen Sizes and Densites](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html)
- [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

They do not give the information/statistics that I am looking for. Judging from the second link, the two most important screen categories to support are `normal-hdpi` and `normal-mdpi`.

The problem is that simply knowing that these two categories are the most popular is of no help to me. The website gives me a range of screen sizes and densities that go into these categories, but the ranges are quite large.

I want to know what the most popular phones are in these two categories. More specifically, I am looking for the **most popular resolutions** in these two categories.

Comment: I finally did my own investigation on this: http://jacksonkr.com/content/basic-android-device-resolutions

Comment: How is [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) unhelpful? It breaks down the information you're asking about into precise percentages, irregardless of phone/tablet models. It even shows pretty pie graphs. If you don't understand what the sizes and DPIs represent, then you really should go back and learn the basics.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy I think it's unhelpful because it doesn't outline the popularity of different dimensions. For example, different devices can be 2:3, 3:4, 3:5, 5:8, 5:9, 9:16, or something in-between.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy: try to not be so patronizing. Take a normal mdpi 320x480 device and scale up images as you should. On many devices the images will still be off. For example Samsung galaxy S4 has 1080 x 1920 pixels. Devices have different ratios, and an updated list on the most common ones would be a great help.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can see the resolutions for those categories in the Table 2, in this section: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest I've seen to what I'm looking for.

Comment: That link says nothing of how common a resolution is... just a table describing which one exists/categories?

Comment: Just put the table together with the link in the answer below (by jimkberry)

Comment: Unfortunately the link no longer lists actual pixel dimensions. See other answers for up-to-date data.

Answer (score 153):

### [DEVELOPER-DOCS](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

---

- `240*320-ldpi`
- `240*400-ldpi`
- `240*432-ldpi`

---

- `320*480-mdpi`
- `480*800-mdpi`
- `480*854-mdpi`
- `1024*600-mdpi`
- `1280*800-mdpi`

---

- `480*800-hdpi`
- `480*854-hdpi`
- `280*280-hdpi`
- `320*320-hdpi`

---

- `720*1280-xhdpi`
- `1200*1290-xhdpi`
- `2560*1600-xhdpi`
- `768*1280-xhdpi`

---

- `1080*1920-xxhdpi`
- `800*1280-tvdpi`

---

### ***I use these reference to make my app***

Quoting an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009368/1083093) from  another stackOverflow post for more details

```
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
Device                          Inches  ResolutionPX    Density         DPI     ResolutionDP    AspectRatios        SysNavYorN  ContentResolutionDP
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------                                                          
Galaxy Y                                 320 x  240     ldpi    0.75    120      427 x 320      4:3     1.3333                   427 x 320
?                                        400 x  240     ldpi    0.75    120      533 x 320      5:3     1.6667                   533 x 320
?                                        432 x  240     ldpi    0.75    120      576 x 320      9:5     1.8000                   576 x 320
Galaxy Ace                               480 x  320     mdpi    1       160      480 x 320      3:2     1.5000                   480 x 320
Nexus S                                  800 x  480     hdpi    1.5     240      533 x 320      5:3     1.6667                   533 x 320
"Galaxy SIII    Mini"                    800 x  480     hdpi    1.5     240      533 x 320      5:3     1.6667                   533 x 320
?                                        854 x  480     hdpi    1.5     240      569 x 320      427:240 1.7792                   569 x 320

Galaxy SIII                             1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Galaxy Nexus                            1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
HTC One X                       4.7"    1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Nexus 5                         5"      1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778      YES          592 x 360
Galaxy S4                       5"      1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
HTC One                         5"      1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Galaxy Note III                 5.7"    1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
HTC One Max                     5.9"    1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Galaxy Note II                  5.6"    1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Nexus 4                         4.4"    1200 x  768     xhdpi   2       320      600 x 384      25:16   1.5625      YES          552 x 384
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
Device                          Inches  ResolutionPX    Density         DPI     ResolutionDP    AspectRatios        SysNavYorN  ContentResolutionDP
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
?                                        800 x  480     mdpi    1       160      800 x 480      5:3     1.6667                   800 x 480
?                                        854 x  480     mdpi    1       160      854 x 480      427:240 1.7792                   854 x 480
Galaxy Mega                     6.3"    1280 x  720     hdpi    1.5     240      853 x 480      16:9    1.7778                   853 x 480
Kindle Fire HD                  7"      1280 x  800     hdpi    1.5     240      853 x 533      8:5     1.6000                   853 x 533
Galaxy Mega                     5.8"     960 x  540     tvdpi   1.33333 213.333  720 x 405      16:9    1.7778                   720 x 405
Sony Xperia Z Ultra             6.4"    1920 x 1080     xhdpi   2       320      960 x 540      16:9    1.7778                   960 x 540

Kindle Fire (1st & 2nd gen)     7"      1024 x  600     mdpi    1       160     1024 x 600      128:75  1.7067                  1024 x 600
Tesco Hudl                      7"      1400 x  900     hdpi    1.5     240      933 x 600      14:9    1.5556                   933 x 600
Nexus 7 (1st gen/2012)          7"      1280 x  800     tvdpi   1.33333 213.333  960 x 600      8:5     1.6000      YES          912 x 600
Nexus 7 (2nd gen/2013)          7"      1824 x 1200     xhdpi   2       320      912 x 600      38:25   1.5200      YES          864 x 600
Kindle Fire HDX                 7"      1920 x 1200     xhdpi   2       320      960 x 600      8:5     1.6000                   960 x 600
?                                        800 x  480     ldpi    0.75    120     1067 x 640      5:3     1.6667                  1067 x 640
?                                        854 x  480     ldpi    0.75    120     1139 x 640      427:240 1.7792                  1139 x 640

Kindle Fire HD                  8.9"    1920 x 1200     hdpi    1.5     240     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Kindle Fire HDX                 8.9"    2560 x 1600     xhdpi   2       320     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Galaxy Tab 2                    10"     1280 x  800     mdpi    1       160     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Galaxy Tab 3                    10"     1280 x  800     mdpi    1       160     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
ASUS Transformer                10"     1280 x  800     mdpi    1       160     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
ASUS Transformer 2              10"     1920 x 1200     hdpi    1.5     240     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Nexus 10                        10"     2560 x  1600    xhdpi   2       320     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Galaxy Note 10.1                10"     2560 x  1600    xhdpi   2       320     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
Device                          Inches  ResolutionPX    Density         DPI     ResolutionDP    AspectRatios        SysNavYorN  ContentResolutionDP
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
```

Comment: Hi, for your reference is very useful for me, but i have some doubt. You are mentioned various resolution sizes in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi like that. Now i going to develop fully images app. I get image from designer, I need to asking him for which resolution size of images in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can I use that for layout folders ?

Answer (score 50):

Also, their "device dashboard" stats at:

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens

can be pretty helpful. They are current and derived from Android Market visits.

Comment: This is a correct answer

Answer (score 42):

Another alternative to see **popular android resolutions or aspect ratios** is **Unity** statistics:

[**LATEST UNITY STATISTICS (on 2019.06 return http503)**](http://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/display-android.html) [web arhive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718023014/https://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/display-android.html)

Top on **2017-01**:

**Display Resolutions:**

- 1280 x 720: 28.9%
- 1920 x 1080: 21.4%
- 800 x 480: 10.3%
- 854 x 480: 9.7%
- 960 x 540: 8.9%
- 1024 x 600: 7.8%
- 1280 x 800: 5.0%
- 2560 x 1440: 2.4%
- 480 x 320: 1.2%
- 1920 x 1200: 0.8%
- 1024 x 768: 0.8%

**Display Aspect Ratios:**

- 16:9: 72.4%
- 5:3: 18.2%
- 16:10: 6.2%
- 4:3: 1.7%
- 3:2: 1.2%
- 5:4: 0.1%

Answer (score 33):

Here is a list of almost all resolutions of tablets, with the most common ones in **bold** :

2560X1600
1366X768

**1920X1200**
**1280X800**
**1280X768**
**1024X800**
**1024X768**
**1024X600**

960X640
960X540
854X480
800X600
**800X480**
**800X400**

Happy designing .. ! :)

Comment: Nexus 7 2013 is 1920 x 1200 
Amazon Kindle Fire HDX 7 is 1920 x 1200
Sony Xperia Tablet Z is 1920 x 1200
Why is this resolution not listed?

Comment: @Gomoku7 done!. thanks for informing (:

Comment: Which device is 800x400? That makes no sense as all resolutions have to fit between 16:9 and 4:3.

Comment: ya thats the klnd of fragmentation shit android developers have to deal with. There are some cheap android tablets (iBall, MicroMax) which have devices with such resolutions

Comment: How about Low resolutions? 240x320 320x480 etc...

Answer (score 8):

A blog article from Localytics, [Android Not As Fragmented as Many Think](http://www.localytics.com/blog/2012/android-not-as-fragmented-as-many-think/), lists most popular Android sizes and resolutions:

> Another concern for Android developers is screen size and resolution. Of all app usage analyzed for this study, 41% of all sessions came from Android devices with 4.3 inch screens, by far the most popular size. 4 inch screens accounted for 22% of sessions, 3.2 inch screens for 11%, and 3.7 inch screens contributed 9%.
>
> Resolutions were even less fragmented, however, with the most widely-seen screen resolution – 800 x 480 pixels – contributing 62% of the study’s sessions. The next most popular screen resolutions were 480 x 320 (14%), 960 x 540 (6%), 480 x 854 (5%) and 320 x 240 (5%).

Please note these statistics are from February 2012, which might be outdated today. Also, please always keep in mind that your app might be used under the inch sizes and resolutions not listed in this article.

**EDIT:** You should also be aware that there are Android "tablets" with large resolutions. The following quote is from the same article I mentioned:

> Screen resolution and size are actually even less fragmented than handsets – 74% of Android tablet usage takes place on 7 inch devices with 1024 x 600 resolution. 22% are 10.1 inch devices with 1280 x 800 resolutions, so by taking into account two screen size/resolution combinations, developers should be able to easily reach nearly all of the Android tablet market.

Answer (score 7):

There is now official Device Metrics on the Material Design site, those metrics are a hand picked devices list, not an actual statistics, but it too can be really helpful: https://material.io/devices/

Answer (score 3):

The vast majority of current android 2.1+ phone screens are 480x800 (or in the case of motodroid oddities, 480x854)

However, this doesn't mean this should be your only concern.  You need to make it looking good on tablets, and smaller or 4:3 ratio smaller screens.

RelativeLayout is your friend!