# Is there a list of screen resolutions for all Android based phones and tablets?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

If not, is there a list of screen resolutions for the most popular Android phones and tablets.

Comment: Read this https://design.google.com/devices/  perhaps help you .

Comment: @user783146 is there any website that provides screen resolutions for pre-release devices?

Answer (score 138):

(out of date) Spreadsheet of device metrics.

**SEE ALSO:**
[Device Metrics - Material Design](https://material.io/devices/).
[Screen Sizes](http://screensiz.es/phone).

```
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
Device                          Inches  ResolutionPX    Density         DPI     ResolutionDP    AspectRatios        SysNavYorN  ContentResolutionDP
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------                                                          
Galaxy Y                                 320 x  240     ldpi    0.75    120      427 x 320      4:3     1.3333                   427 x 320
?                                        400 x  240     ldpi    0.75    120      533 x 320      5:3     1.6667                   533 x 320
?                                        432 x  240     ldpi    0.75    120      576 x 320      9:5     1.8000                   576 x 320
Galaxy Ace                               480 x  320     mdpi    1       160      480 x 320      3:2     1.5000                   480 x 320
Nexus S                                  800 x  480     hdpi    1.5     240      533 x 320      5:3     1.6667                   533 x 320
"Galaxy SIII    Mini"                    800 x  480     hdpi    1.5     240      533 x 320      5:3     1.6667                   533 x 320
?                                        854 x  480     hdpi    1.5     240      569 x 320      427:240 1.7792                   569 x 320

Galaxy SIII                             1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Galaxy Nexus                            1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
HTC One X                       4.7"    1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Nexus 5                         5"      1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778      YES          592 x 360
Galaxy S4                       5"      1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
HTC One                         5"      1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Galaxy Note III                 5.7"    1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
HTC One Max                     5.9"    1920 x 1080     xxhdpi  3       480      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Galaxy Note II                  5.6"    1280 x  720     xhdpi   2       320      640 x 360      16:9    1.7778                   640 x 360
Nexus 4                         4.4"    1200 x  768     xhdpi   2       320      600 x 384      25:16   1.5625      YES          552 x 384
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
Device                          Inches  ResolutionPX    Density         DPI     ResolutionDP    AspectRatios        SysNavYorN  ContentResolutionDP
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
?                                        800 x  480     mdpi    1       160      800 x 480      5:3     1.6667                   800 x 480
?                                        854 x  480     mdpi    1       160      854 x 480      427:240 1.7792                   854 x 480
Galaxy Mega                     6.3"    1280 x  720     hdpi    1.5     240      853 x 480      16:9    1.7778                   853 x 480
Kindle Fire HD                  7"      1280 x  800     hdpi    1.5     240      853 x 533      8:5     1.6000                   853 x 533
Galaxy Mega                     5.8"     960 x  540     tvdpi   1.33333 213.333  720 x 405      16:9    1.7778                   720 x 405
Sony Xperia Z Ultra             6.4"    1920 x 1080     xhdpi   2       320      960 x 540      16:9    1.7778                   960 x 540
Blackberry Priv                 5.43"   2560 x 1440     ?               540          ?          16:9    1.7778      
Blackberry Passport             4.5"    1440 x 1440     ?               453          ?          1:1     1.0     

Kindle Fire (1st & 2nd gen)     7"      1024 x  600     mdpi    1       160     1024 x 600      128:75  1.7067                  1024 x 600
Tesco Hudl                      7"      1400 x  900     hdpi    1.5     240      933 x 600      14:9    1.5556                   933 x 600
Nexus 7 (1st gen/2012)          7"      1280 x  800     tvdpi   1.33333 213.333  960 x 600      8:5     1.6000      YES          912 x 600
Nexus 7 (2nd gen/2013)          7"      1824 x 1200     xhdpi   2       320      912 x 600      38:25   1.5200      YES          864 x 600
Kindle Fire HDX                 7"      1920 x 1200     xhdpi   2       320      960 x 600      8:5     1.6000                   960 x 600
?                                        800 x  480     ldpi    0.75    120     1067 x 640      5:3     1.6667                  1067 x 640
?                                        854 x  480     ldpi    0.75    120     1139 x 640      427:240 1.7792                  1139 x 640

Kindle Fire HD                  8.9"    1920 x 1200     hdpi    1.5     240     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Kindle Fire HDX                 8.9"    2560 x 1600     xhdpi   2       320     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Galaxy Tab 2                    10"     1280 x  800     mdpi    1       160     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Galaxy Tab 3                    10"     1280 x  800     mdpi    1       160     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
ASUS Transformer                10"     1280 x  800     mdpi    1       160     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
ASUS Transformer 2              10"     1920 x 1200     hdpi    1.5     240     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Nexus 10                        10"     2560 x  1600    xhdpi   2       320     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
Galaxy Note 10.1                10"     2560 x  1600    xhdpi   2       320     1280 x 800      8:5     1.6000                  1280 x 800
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
Device                          Inches  ResolutionPX    Density         DPI     ResolutionDP    AspectRatios        SysNavYorN  ContentResolutionDP
---------------------------     -----   ------------    --------------- ------- -----------     ----------------    ---         ----------
```

---

**Coping with different aspect ratios**

The different aspect ratios seen above are (from most square; h/w):

```
1:1     1.0     <- rare for phone; common for watch
4:3     1.3333  <- matches iPad (when portrait)
3:2     1.5000
38:25   1.5200
14:9    1.5556  <- rare
25:16   1.5625
8:5     1.6000  <- aka 16:10
5:3     1.6667
128:75  1.7067
16:9    1.7778  <- matches iPhone 5-7
427:240 1.7792  <- rare
37:18   2.0555  <- Galaxy S8
```

If you skip the extreme aspect ratios, that are rarely seen at phone size or larger, **all the other devices fit a range from 1.3333 to 1.7778, which conveniently matches the current iPhone/iPad ratios (considering all devices in portrait mode)**. Note that there are quite a few variations within that range, so if you are creating a small number of fixed aspect-ratio layouts, you will need to decide how to handle the odd "in-between" screens.

Minimum "portrait mode" solution is to support 1.3333, which results in unused space at top and bottom, on all the resolutions with larger aspect ratio.
Most likely, you would instead design it to stretch over the 1.333 to 1.778 range. But sometimes part of your design looks too distorted then.

---

Advanced layout ideas:

> For text, you can design for 1.3333, then increase line spacing for 1.666 - though that will look quite sparse. **For graphics, design for an intermediate ratio**, so that on some screens it is slightly squashed, on others it is slightly stretched. geometric mean of Sqrt(1333 x 1667) ~= 1491. So you design for 1491 x 1000, which will be stretched/squashed by +-12% when assigned to the extreme cases.

Next refinement is to design **layout as a stack of different-height "bands" that each fill the width of the screen**. Then determine where you can most pleasingly "stretch-or-squash" a band's height, to adjust for different ratios.

> For example, consider imaginary phones with 1333 x 1000 pixels and 1666 x 1000 pixels. Suppose you have two "bands", and your main "band" is square, so it is 1000 x 1000. Second band is 333 x 1000 on one screen, 666 x 1000 on the other - quite a range to design for.
>   You might decide your main band looks okay altered 10% up-or-down, and squash it 900 x 1000 on the 1333 x 1000 screen, leaving 433 x 1000. Then stretch it to 1100 x 1000 on 1666 x 1000 screen, leaving 566 x 1000. So your second band now needs to adjust over only 433 to 566, which has geometric mean of Sqrt(433 x 566) ~= 495. So you design for 495 x 1000, which will be stretched/squashed by +-14% when assigned to the extreme cases.

Comment: Very useful. Are you sure Sony Xperia Z Ultra is xhdpi (not xxhdpi as all other full-hd phones)? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: No I am not sure, a lot of these values were looked up from random databases on the interwebs and their results didn't always fill me with complete confidence.

Comment: Hi any updatedsheet available?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been working on any Android projects in months and thus I haven't been updating this information, so no.

Comment: Can you make this a community wiki page?

Comment: It is so (I think, I just edited and checked the 'community wiki' checkbox).

Comment: how can i make a layout for each ?

Comment: Plus 1 for providing current links AND for doing this in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a list of almost all resolutions of tablets :

2560*1600
1366*768
1280*800
1280*768
1024*768
1024*600
960*640
960*540
854*480
800*600
800*480
800*400

Of this, the most common resolutions are :

1280*800
1280*768
1024*600
1024*800
1024*768
800*400
800*480

Happy designing  .. ! :)

Comment: Now, that's finally on-point!

Comment: What are their dp resolution equivalents thought?

Comment: @HaggleLad : That depends on the screen size of the device.

Comment: Exactly, a list of popular pixel resolutions is largely useless since no Android developer should be coding Views in pixels.  What would be great is a list of the most popular resolutions in DP units.

Comment: my phone is 1920x720 resolution. How can I design the application using android studio.

Answer (score 21):

These are the sizes. Try to take a look in [Supporting Mutiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

I use this to make more than one layout:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: 360dp: larger phone screen like galaxy s3, s4, galaxy note 3 (1280x720 xhdpi, 1920x1080 xxhdpi, etc.). For detailed info see Oliver Pearmain's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets#23009368

Comment: Note that those sizes don't indicate anything about *aspect ratio*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009368/199364 - "*Coping with different aspect ratios*" for a discussion of the range of aspect ratios that are common.

Answer (score 15):

Google recently added this comprehensive list of reference devices and resolutions, including new device types such as wearables and laptops:

https://design.google.com/devices/

Comment: this is the perfect answer

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unless I'm missing something, that list is far too short to be considered all inclusive. People are keeping phones longer today so there are still a lot of older phones out there. Apps that want or need to support those (e.g. Galaxy S3/S4 and many more) have to handle those too, and they're conspicuously missing from the list.

Comment: Looks like they deleted the list and replaced it with some article. Meh.

Answer (score 4):

You can see a lot of screen sizes on [this site](http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php).

[Parsed list of screens](http://pastebin.com/sc6fcgNi):

```
From http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

####################################################################################################
#    Filter out same-sized same-dp screens and width/height swap.
####################################################################################################
Size: 2560 x 1600 px (1280 x 800 dp) xhdpi
Size: 2048 x 1536 px (1024 x 768 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (1442 x 901 dp) tvdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (1280 x 800 dp) hdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (960 x 600 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (640 x 400 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1152 px (640 x 384 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (1920 x 1080 dp) mdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (1280 x 720 dp) hdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (960 x 540 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (640 x 360 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 1600 x 1200 px (1066 x 800 dp) hdpi
Size: 1600 x 900 px (1600 x 900 dp) mdpi
Size: 1440 x 904 px (960 x 602 dp) hdpi
Size: 1366 x 768 px (1366 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1360 x 768 px (1360 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 960 px (640 x 480 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (1280 x 800 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (961 x 600 dp) tvdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (853 x 533 dp) hdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (640 x 400 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1280 x 768 px (1280 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 768 px (640 x 384 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (1280 x 720 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (961 x 540 dp) tvdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (853 x 480 dp) hdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (640 x 360 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1279 x 720 px (639 x 360 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1152 x 720 px (1152 x 720 dp) mdpi
Size: 1080 x 607 px (720 x 404 dp) hdpi
Size: 1024 x 960 px (1024 x 960 dp) mdpi
Size: 1024 x 770 px (1024 x 770 dp) mdpi
Size: 1024 x 768 px (1365 x 1024 dp) ldpi
Size: 1024 x 768 px (1024 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1024 x 768 px (512 x 384 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1024 x 600 px (1365 x 800 dp) ldpi
Size: 1024 x 600 px (1024 x 600 dp) mdpi
Size: 1024 x 600 px (682 x 400 dp) hdpi
Size: 960 x 640 px (480 x 320 dp) xhdpi
Size: 960 x 600 px (960 x 600 dp) ldpi
Size: 960 x 540 px (640 x 360 dp) hdpi
Size: 864 x 480 px (576 x 320 dp) hdpi
Size: 854 x 480 px (569 x 320 dp) hdpi
Size: 800 x 600 px (1066 x 800 dp) ldpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (1066 x 640 dp) ldpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (800 x 480 dp) mdpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (600 x 360 dp) tvdpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (533 x 320 dp) hdpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (266 x 160 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 768 x 576 px (768 x 576 dp) mdpi
Size: 640 x 480 px (640 x 480 dp) mdpi
Size: 640 x 360 px (426 x 240 dp) hdpi
Size: 480 x 320 px (480 x 320 dp) mdpi
Size: 480 x 320 px (320 x 213 dp) hdpi
Size: 432 x 240 px (576 x 320 dp) ldpi
Size: 400 x 240 px (533 x 320 dp) ldpi
Size: 320 x 240 px (426 x 320 dp) ldpi
Size: 280 x 280 px (186 x 186 dp) hdpi

####################################################################################################
#    Sorted by smallest width.
####################################################################################################
sw800dp:
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (1920 x 1080 dp) mdpi
Size: 1024 x 768 px (1365 x 1024 dp) ldpi
Size: 1024 x 960 px (1024 x 960 dp) mdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (1442 x 901 dp) tvdpi
Size: 1600 x 900 px (1600 x 900 dp) mdpi
Size: 800 x 600 px (1066 x 800 dp) ldpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (1280 x 800 dp) hdpi
Size: 1024 x 600 px (1365 x 800 dp) ldpi
Size: 2560 x 1600 px (1280 x 800 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (1280 x 800 dp) mdpi
Size: 1600 x 1200 px (1066 x 800 dp) hdpi

sw720dp:
Size: 1024 x 770 px (1024 x 770 dp) mdpi
Size: 1366 x 768 px (1366 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 768 px (1280 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 2048 x 1536 px (1024 x 768 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1360 x 768 px (1360 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1024 x 768 px (1024 x 768 dp) mdpi
Size: 1152 x 720 px (1152 x 720 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (1280 x 720 dp) mdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (1280 x 720 dp) hdpi

sw600dp:
Size: 800 x 480 px (1066 x 640 dp) ldpi
Size: 1440 x 904 px (960 x 602 dp) hdpi
Size: 960 x 600 px (960 x 600 dp) ldpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (961 x 600 dp) tvdpi
Size: 1024 x 600 px (1024 x 600 dp) mdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (960 x 600 dp) xhdpi

sw480dp:
Size: 768 x 576 px (768 x 576 dp) mdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (960 x 540 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (961 x 540 dp) tvdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (853 x 533 dp) hdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (853 x 480 dp) hdpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (800 x 480 dp) mdpi
Size: 1280 x 960 px (640 x 480 dp) xhdpi
Size: 640 x 480 px (640 x 480 dp) mdpi

sw320dp:
Size: 1080 x 607 px (720 x 404 dp) hdpi
Size: 1024 x 600 px (682 x 400 dp) hdpi
Size: 1280 x 800 px (640 x 400 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1200 px (640 x 400 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 1280 x 768 px (640 x 384 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1024 x 768 px (512 x 384 dp) xhdpi
Size: 1920 x 1152 px (640 x 384 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 1279 x 720 px (639 x 360 dp) xhdpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (600 x 360 dp) tvdpi
Size: 960 x 540 px (640 x 360 dp) hdpi
Size: 1920 x 1080 px (640 x 360 dp) xxhdpi
Size: 1280 x 720 px (640 x 360 dp) xhdpi
Size: 432 x 240 px (576 x 320 dp) ldpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (533 x 320 dp) hdpi
Size: 960 x 640 px (480 x 320 dp) xhdpi
Size: 864 x 480 px (576 x 320 dp) hdpi
Size: 854 x 480 px (569 x 320 dp) hdpi
Size: 480 x 320 px (480 x 320 dp) mdpi
Size: 400 x 240 px (533 x 320 dp) ldpi
Size: 320 x 240 px (426 x 320 dp) ldpi

sw240dp:
Size: 640 x 360 px (426 x 240 dp) hdpi

lower:
Size: 480 x 320 px (320 x 213 dp) hdpi
Size: 280 x 280 px (186 x 186 dp) hdpi
Size: 800 x 480 px (266 x 160 dp) xxhdpi

####################################################################################################
#    Different size in px only.
####################################################################################################
2560 x 1600 px
2048 x 1536 px
1920 x 1200 px
1920 x 1152 px
1920 x 1080 px
1600 x 1200 px
1600 x 900 px
1440 x 904 px
1366 x 768 px
1360 x 768 px
1280 x 960 px
1280 x 800 px
1280 x 768 px
1280 x 720 px
1279 x 720 px
1152 x 720 px
1080 x 607 px
1024 x 960 px
1024 x 770 px
1024 x 768 px
1024 x 600 px
960 x 640 px
960 x 600 px
960 x 540 px
864 x 480 px
854 x 480 px
800 x 600 px
800 x 480 px
768 x 576 px
640 x 480 px
640 x 360 px
480 x 320 px
432 x 240 px
400 x 240 px
320 x 240 px
280 x 280 px

####################################################################################################
#    Different size in dp only.
####################################################################################################
1920 x 1080 dp
1600 x 900 dp
1442 x 901 dp
1366 x 768 dp
1365 x 1024 dp
1365 x 800 dp
1360 x 768 dp
1280 x 800 dp
1280 x 768 dp
1280 x 720 dp
1152 x 720 dp
1066 x 800 dp
1066 x 640 dp
1024 x 960 dp
1024 x 770 dp
1024 x 768 dp
1024 x 600 dp
961 x 600 dp
961 x 540 dp
960 x 602 dp
960 x 600 dp
960 x 540 dp
853 x 533 dp
853 x 480 dp
800 x 480 dp
768 x 576 dp
720 x 404 dp
682 x 400 dp
640 x 480 dp
640 x 400 dp
640 x 384 dp
640 x 360 dp
639 x 360 dp
600 x 360 dp
576 x 320 dp
569 x 320 dp
533 x 320 dp
512 x 384 dp
480 x 320 dp
426 x 320 dp
426 x 240 dp
320 x 213 dp
266 x 160 dp
186 x 186 dp
```

I drop a lot of same-sized same-dp screens, ignore height/width swap and include some sorting results.

Answer (score 2):

hdpi  480x800 px    Samsung S2

xhdpi 720x1280  px -    Nexus 4     phone   - 4.7,4.8 inches
            Samsung Galaxy S3
            Motorola Moto G

xxhdpi 1080x1920 px -   Nexus 5     phone   -  4.95 inches 
            Samsung Galaxy S4
                Samsung Galaxy S5
            Samsung Galaxy Note 3   -  5.7 inches
                LG G2
            HTC One M8
            HTC One M9
                Sony Xperia Z1
            Sony Xperia Z2
            Sony Xperia Z3
            Sony Xperia Z3+

xxxhdpi 1440x2560 px -  Nexus 6     phablet -  6 inches
                Samsung S6
            Samsung S6 Edge
            Samsung Galaxy Note 4   - 5.7 inches
            LG G3
            LG G4

xxhdpi 1920×1200 px -   Nexus 7     tablet  -  7 inches
            Sony Z3 Tablet Compact
            LG G Pad 8.3        -  8.3 inches
            Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet   -  10.1 inches

xxxhdpi 2560×1600 px -  Nexus 10    tablet  -  10.1 inches
            ~Google Nexus 9
            Sony Xperia Z4 tablet
            Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2
            Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1
            Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 
            Dell Venue 8 7840