# How to make device use proper layout resource file?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

So basically I have finished creating different layout sizes and put them in their respective folders(i.e layout-large, layout-xlarge, etc). Now I am struggling with getting the device to use the correct layout, because when I run the app on my phone(Oneplus One, 5.5") it doesn't use the layout resource file from "layout-large", but instead the file just named "layout". I thought this may have something to do with how in the Java code setContentView says 
    `R.layout.activity_main`
Not sure how to fix this. What do I do so the device uses the proper layout resource file?

Comment: for 5.5 inch u should make layout-large-mdpi.

Comment: ok I'll do that then.

Comment: Have you used the same name for all the layout files ?

Comment: yeah I did use the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OnePlus One is not large screen size. It's Normal Screen size with XXDPI and resolution in dp is 640x360dp

So, your resouce folder must be layout-normal not layout-large

Ps. All android phone with 5+ inch still have Normal Screen size. I found only Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 which 6+" screen size that be Large screen size. (I'm not sure about Nexus 6 until I get a data from it)

Comment: Oh ok I didn't realize this, because when I created the layout-large it displayed the preview in a 5.1 screen. I will try this.

Comment: Actually I remember going on the Android dev site, and was wondering why they have a picture where it says 5.5 inches come under large... Is that picture incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

u need to copy all layouts in **layout-large-mdpi** folder. and resize ur images to fit in that screen and create **drawable-large-mdpi (res/drawable-large-mdpi)** and add images and u also need to create **values-large-mdpi** and add your dimen file with dimensions..

and check out these links hope help you

[Different resolution support android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device/16910589#16910589)

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

[Is there a list of screen resolutions for all Android based phones and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets)

Comment: Actually there are no images. The problem I have is the device isn't using the layout from the folder it should be using. It's just using the main layout, but thanks anyway

Comment: k. just paste you xml layouts in **layout-large-mdpi** folder..if you are using hard code dimensions like height=50dp etc use dimen file.