# Android layout for Nexus4 vs Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-layout

I preview my Android app in a Nexus 4 :). Here it is

[image]

But when I try to preview it on a Nexus 7 emulator, :(

[image]

I think that I'm having issues on supporting multiple screens on my game.
My question is, how can I make it look bigger on nexus 7 or 10 or any other devices?

By the way, I placed my images (board.png,small_hole.png, big_hole.png and bg.png) on drawable-xhdpi folder (I'm using Android Studio)

Do you think I used the wrong layout or properties in my xml file? Is there something wrong in my code?

This is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg.png>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/big_hole" >
            </ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/small_hole" >
                </ImageView>

                // paste 6 more ImageViews here

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/small_hole" >
                </ImageView>

               // paste 6 more ImageViews here

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/big_hole" >
            </ImageView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

thank you guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus 4 access `drawable-xhdpi` resources and

Nexus 7 access `drawable-large-tvdpi` or `drawable-sw600dp-tvdpi` resources.

Nexus 10 access `drawable-xlarge-xhdpi` or `drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi` resources.

and u should resize ur image and u shud put in respective folders.

and Nexus 4 is 4.7 inch (768*1280) of size and Nexus 7 is 7 inch (800*1280) of size.

more info:

[Different resolution support android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device/16910589#16910589)

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

[Is there a list of screen resolutions for all Android based phones and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets)

Comment: welcome buddy..use `drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi` for nexus 10

Answer (score 0):

Try placing youre images in res/mdpi they will be streched to fit screens which are bigger (hdpi, xhdpi)
(if i remember correctly the modyfiers are x1.5 and x2 for hdpi and xhdpi).

Alternatevly you can make a layout folder for larger screens ie. layout-sw720dp and create a new layout file there.