# Tablet UI doesn't work on my app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to create an app which has two different UIs for tablets and phones, and I'm using fragments to implement this. I have created two separate xml files for each tablet and phone layout and both are called activity_main.xml, with the phone layout being placed in the res/layout folder and the tablet layout being placed in the res/layout-sw600dp folder.

However when I try to run my app on a Nexus 10 emulator(Android Studio), it automatically goes to the default phone layout. The app doesn't crash or anything but it just runs in the phone UI when it's supposed to run in tablet UI. I dont know what the source of this error could be and so any help would be appreciated.

Here's an update, I tried renaming the folder to res/layout-large-mdpi but still found no change. Is it possible that it might have something to do with the emulator?

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidattack.www.sunshine" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.androidattack.www.sunshine"
            android:name=".data.WeatherProvider" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

sw600dp layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:name="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.ForecastFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container">

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

normal layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
    android:name="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.ForecastFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context="com.androidattack.www.sunshine.ForecastFragment"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

And finally this is my MainActivity.java class:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.androidattack.www.sunshine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (findViewById(R.id.weather_detail_container) != null) {
            // Tablet view
            mTwoPane = true;

            // In two-pane mode, show the detail view by adding
            // or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.weather_detail_container, new DetailFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        } else {
            // Phone View
            mTwoPane = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_map) {
            openPreferredLocationInMap();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openPreferredLocationInMap() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String location = sharedPrefs.getString(
                getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_location_default));

        // Using the URI scheme for showing a location found on a map.  This super-handy
        // intent can is detailed in the "Common Intents" page of Android's developer site:
        // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps
        Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("q", location)
                .build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(geoLocation);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't call " + location + ", no receiving apps installed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other resource folders with qualifiers? Maybe one of those is taking priority over your sw600dp folder?

Comment: did you try in real device? In my nexus 7, I can archive it with values-sw6000dp. Maybe you can try to create folder values-sw720dp (10" tablet)

Comment: Have you tried layout-large? That's what we use to differentiate our tablet and phone layouts. layout-large gets you both 7" and 10" tablets, and if you need something different for 10" you can use layout-xlarge.

Comment: check these links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device/16910589#16910589

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets

Comment: Technically I should not need to create sw720dp folder or layout-xlarge because all of them have shortest width more than 600dp and should fall in the criteria for sw600dp. So all tablets including 7 inch tablets should work and no I did not try it on a real tablet as I dont possess one.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: I believe that error had something to do with the emulator.

Comment: Hey how did you finally set up your emulator then?

Answer (score 9):

For me, the code was correct, but the issue was with the emulator. If you set your emulator up with `No skin`, it should work. Remove that skin!

Comment: really a gotcha for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Did you try what happens with the layout when you rotate the device? (e.g. as per sunshine project you need to create both layout-sw600dp-port and layout-sw600dp)

Answer (score 0):

layout-sw600dp is for 7 inch tablet/emulator

layout-sw720dp is for 10 inch tablet/emulator

Answer (score -2):

Using layout-xhdpi will work for this specific scenario and a Nexus 7 or 10 tablet emulator for the Nanodegree. I could never get the layout-sw600dp to properly load on my emulator and instead I currently maintain Sunshine with both a layout-xhdpi and a layout-sw600dp with the same activity_main.xml.

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of making some phones also get the layout. There has to be a better solution.