# Android Determine tablet screen size

Tags: android, user-interface, android-drawable

We have different densities for different phone sizes as it is given in google developer website

36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Now if i have an image of size 60x60 for mdpi phone then i can calculate all other sizes by multiplying 60 by (1.5, 2.0, 3.0 or 4.0). Then how do i calculate the size of images for tablet? If i can put it simply what should i tell graphic designer to provide me if i am going to build a new app that will support both phone and tablet?

Comment: you can try these sizes

`72x72 (1.0x baseline) for 540dp-medium-density                   
108x108 (1.5x) for 540dp-high-density               
144x144 (2.0x) for 540dp-extra-high-density               
216x216 (3.0x) for 540dp-extra-extra-high-density   `

Comment: But these sizes are not foolproof. Some of the icons will have to be resized after viewing them on device. And I have omitted ldpi and xxxhpi to reduce apk size..

Answer (score 0):

We created some application for tablet's. We create Two different Layout folder's in res directory, as follows res/layout-sw600dp/ & res/layout-sw720dp/ . In these folder's we Put all layout files and manage them to set for Tablet screen's. you can go with following device resolution for tablet screen's

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

for more info, just check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Hey dear may be it will help you..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009368/1083093

Comment: you havent got my points i am talking about drawable sizes, how can i determine drawable size for diffrent tablet densities. Lets say if i have an image of size 60x60 for phone mdpi and i want to create this image for 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi) how i can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Like phones, tablets have defined dpi too. If you are creating a drawable for a xxhdpi phone it'll be the same for a xxhdpi tablet.

Comment: i dont think so, if you have an image for phone mdpi density it wont work as it is for 7” tablet mdpi

Comment: Can you tell me which tablet are you using?

Comment: Is the display size 10 inch?

Comment: unfortunately, your tablet's screen has a couple of pixels missing to be hdpi device (its 214dpi, whilst hdpi=240dpi & mdpi=160dpi). I think you should create a drawable-sw600 folder & put it's drawables in it & tell your designer to scale this png files as mdpi size multiplied by 1.3.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is Android Assets Studio. It does all the work following the official best practices.

**Here is the link:**

> https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

First you need to read these:

> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You might probably need this:

> https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: thanks for response. i know about androidassetstudio but i dont know how i can generate all assets for both phone and tablet for all screen sizes and densities. Can you elaborate a little about android asset studio?

Comment: in this link we provide an image of certain density and it generate outputs of densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). If i have an image for phone device of density xxhdpi then it will give me all other densities for device. How can i get images of all densities for tablet? As i am newbie so sorry if couldn't get it

Comment: It selects automatically from the folder based on the device and screen sizes, and scales to work best on different devices and screen...