# React native responsiveness issue

Tags: react-native

I am using `flex`, `EStyleSheet` and `$rem`.  I am avoiding absolute values of height, width, margin and using `%` everywhere for my components. However, on different screen resolutions, the position of my components looks different.

E.g `My company` logo is lower on a smaller (or because of Android/iOS) screen and also there is much less space left at the bottom of the page (2nd Image).

Could you please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, ImageBackground, TouchableHighlight, Image, Dimensions} from "react-native";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';


class SignInUpGender extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground style={styles.Image} source={require('../../assets/images/background_loading.png')}>
                <View style={styles.LogoView}>
                    <Text style={styles.Logo}>My company</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.RegistrationView}>

                    <View style={styles.GreetingsView}>
                        <Text style={styles.GreetingsText}>
                            Hey, you are ...
                        </Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.GenderView}>
                        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.GenderButton}
                            onPress={() => this.props.handleNext('MALE')}>
                            <View style={styles.GenderAndIconView}>
                                <Image style={styles.GenderImg} source={require('../../assets/images/gender_male.png')} />
                                <Text style={styles.GenderText}>MALE</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.GenderButton}
                            onPress={() => this.props.handleNext('FEMALE')}>
                            <View style={styles.GenderAndIconView}>
                                <Image style={styles.GenderImg} source={require('../../assets/images/gender_female.png')} />
                                <Text style={styles.GenderText}>FEMALE</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.OrBorderView}>
                        <View style={styles.Border}/>
                        <Text style={styles.OrText}>or</Text>
                        <View style={styles.Border}/>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.AlreadyRegisteredView}>
                        <Text style={styles.AlreadyRegisteredText}>Already registered?</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.SignInText}>Login</Text>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToPros)(SignInUpGender);


const entireScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
EStyleSheet.build({$rem: entireScreenWidth / 380});

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({

    Image: {
        flex : 1,
    },
    LogoView: {
        flex: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    RegistrationView: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    GreetingsView: {
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    GenderView: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    Logo: {
        marginTop: '16%',
        fontSize: '36rem',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        opacity: 0.7,
        letterSpacing: '12rem',
    },
    GenderButton: {
        flex: 1,
        borderRadius:10,
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        borderColor:'#FFFFFF',
        padding: '8rem',
        margin: '2%'
    },
    GenderAndIconView: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    GenderText: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: '16rem',
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    GenderImg: {
        width: '26rem',
        height: '26rem',
    },
    GreetingsText: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: '22rem',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: '5rem'
    },
    OrBorderView: {
        margin: '10rem',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
    Border: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8',
        height: 1,
        borderRadius:1,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    OrText: {
        alignSelf:'center',
        paddingHorizontal:'5rem',
        fontSize: '14rem',
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: '#E8E8E8'
    },
    AlreadyRegisteredView: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    AlreadyRegisteredText: {
        color: '#E8E8E8',
        fontSize: '14rem',
    },
    SignInText:{
        fontSize: '14rem',
        fontWeight: '600',
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        marginLeft: '5rem'
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it between 'screen sizes' or Android and iOS?

Comment: @MCMatan, When I am running on iphone5s there is still less space at the bottom of the page, however, My company logo looks better.

Answer (score 1):

You need has multiples images with aspect ratio from screens, because there has many, [here a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets/23009368#23009368), because when you resize(proportional) image with diferent aspetc this cause distorsion image, or you need center o position image, when you use same aspect ratio you only need resize [image]

So you example is like to next sample image, because aspect ratio is diferent

[image]

in html you can like to :

```
 <picture>
      <source srcset="extralarge.jpg" media="(min-height: 1000px)">
      <source srcset="large.jpg" media="(min-height: 500px)">
      <img srcset="medium.jpg" alt="">
    </picture>
```

css like to:

```
   .img {
  background-image: url(medium.jpg);
}
@media (min-height: 500px) {
  .img {
    background-image: url(large.jpg);
  }
}
@media (min-height: 1000px) {
  .img {
    background-image: url(extralarge.jpg);
  }
}
```

Comment: But if you look at the images why my bottom buttons in android is lower than on Iphone X? This should be nothing to do with image itself.

Comment: becasue width is same , but height not

Comment: but with flex it should be proportionally distributed.

Comment: but if screen has same aspect ratio like to 5:3

Comment: would you mind to update your answer to explain it with more details? I am still not getting it.