# Google Play Console unsupported devices (808)

Tags: android, google-play

I have just released a app on Google Play. It shows unsupported 808 devices out of which some are listed below for reference

> > MICROMAX
> >      A44– tinnoes13_s7050 A45– tinnoes73_s8030_2g P300– crane-M701C_mmx A73– A73 P275– P275

Also some testing on friends devices I realize that Android 4.0 devices, dont show the app on Google Play.

My Manifest file has the following. What am I missing here ? Is there a way to support "all" devices?

```
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="1.18" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 

<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> -->

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="16"
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

I haven't mentioned the app since I dont want to violate SO's rules on self app promotion. If needed, I can mention it on a comment. Just request for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `maxSdkVersion` attribute:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Any device with version > 16 will not show the app, f.e. devices running Android 4.2 (version 17).

Also, since you're requesting the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission, the app will only be shown to devices that have phone capability. If your app can also run on devices that don't have phone capability, make it not required:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Same thing with `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, the app will only be shown for devices that have GPS, unless you make it not required:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions for more info.

Comment: (411 added), super thanks. I need to figure out the remaining devices. But first I'll test if this covers the devices that I need to start with. Thanks again.