# How to make android app work in different resolutions?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've finished app making and now facing issues that the app i just made doesn't work well in phone with varying resolutions like only half view of screen is shown. How can I make it work properly in all smartphones with different resolutions?

Comment: please check documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 3):

You should create multiple .xml files with same name, and add some qualifiers for the size, orientation, country etc in order to make your app works on every devices.

[image] This is what you have when you create new .xml files in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You should create multiple for screen resolution: create layout files like
1.layout-small:in that multiply all dimensions by 0.75
2.layout-large:in that multiply all dimensions by 1.5
3.layout-xlarge: in that multiply all dimensions by 2.0 
Refer following links:
[1]https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
[2][How to set android layout to support all screen sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476662/how-to-set-android-layout-to-support-all-screen-sizes)