# Selecting a different layout directory based on screen Height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

In my application, the `layout` must have a certain look but this is hard to achieve in many different screen resolutions and densities. I've read the **developers article** and tried my best to support many different screens by creating the following `layout` files :

[image: layout dirs]

However, 4.7" phones(1920x1080) and 5.8" phones(like my s8 : 1080x2220) use the same `layout-sw360dp` directory. Due to their difference in screen height resolution, the ui elements don't show up correctly for both phones. I want to know how i should go about solving this problem, can i use another `qualifier` to make android studio select the appropriate `layout` directory based on the phone's height or something? I'm starting to get lost here. Any help is welcome

Comment: Please visit this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476662/how-to-set-android-layout-to-support-all-screen-sizes#29144549), a lot of resources have been referenced there.

Comment: @CoolGuyCG i'm sorry but i've read such posts and they don't help me much. They are too generic. I need to distinguish which layout to choose based on resolution and not just dp etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging even deeper, i found out that you can choose different `layouts` inside the `onCreate()` method based on info from `DisplayMetrics` like so:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;

if (...) {
    setContentView(R.layout.ex1);
} else {
   // .....
}
```

By using the `height` and `width` variables as the conditions inside the if statement , i managed to select the appropriate `layout` files for each screen size!