# Splash Image size

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, screen-resolution

I am using theme instead of layout to show splash screen,but I am confused what resolution images to set for **different screen densities**,because `<item>` tag's width and height attributes available **API>22.**

**Background drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item >
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Style**

```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Splash Image size** for different resolution devices for **portrait**

```
MDPI = 320x480px 

LDPI = 240x360px

HDPI = 480x720px

XHDPI = 640x960px

XXHDPI = 960x1440px

XXXHDPI = 1280x1920px
```

From [***https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html***](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) you can make a 9-patch image for all the resolutions - XHDPI,HDPI,MDPI,LDPI

Comment: Thank you,and is it mandatory to use 9-patch?can i use just image by the resolutions above?

Comment: yes, you can use your images that is just a suggestion.

Comment: But you know actually my drawable is not full screen image,it is small,like app icon

Comment: still 5 to go)  The minimum is 15)

Comment: Ok now :D But how sould I calcualte the size for little image for the center

Comment: not actually. you can generate that size of images and use them

Comment: `MDPI is 320x480 dp = 320x480px (1x)` **FALSE**. **Density** has nothing to do with **resolution**. mdpi is 160**dp**, not 320x480 **px**. The resolution can be anything (in facts, most tablets are mdpi, with a typical resolution of 1024x600). What counts is that, since at mdpi we can assume 1px = 1dp and we know the relation between densities, we have the formula to calculate the resolution for all screen densities.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator you are right but to support diff screen i have given this solution. you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726279/2826147

Comment: Still it is a false idea that mdpi is necessarily 320x480. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272384/most-popular-screen-sizes-resolutions-on-android-phones).